# Can Blender load file gradually？

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

Can I use bpy load big .blend file gradually? My 3D format file are always several Gbs big. If load whole file all at a single time, it takes time.

Comment: You could try [appending](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/linked_libraries/link_append.html) items from the large file into a new file.

Comment: Please don't repost the same question, instead [edit](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/editing) your original question if you wish to add additional information.