# Blender open a large file not at a time, but gradually with command line

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

The business purpose is that I allow registered user upload different 3D model files. When other users review the file, he or she does not need to download the whole file (size about several Gbs), he or she could make preview the 3D model files with the biginning a couple of 3D frames. In this way, he or she could know about the 3D file roughtly, then decide to download or not.

Since the 3d format file is around several Gbs, I could not load the file at once. But I only know the following way of loading a file:

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile(filepath="E:/sjj/Blender/demoFile/Demo_274/Ring_27.blend"
```

The expert in [this link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118202/can-blender-load-file-gradually?noredirect=1#comment206838_118202) suggests me following:

> You could try appending items from the large file into a new file.

But, I do not know how to appending items from the large file into a new file. I checked [another link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81/how-can-i-reuse-existing-materials-objects-etc-from-an-existing-blend) in this forum, it needs graphical UI. With my business purpose, it allow me only uses command line script.

Could some expert show me the code examples?

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean by "3D frames"?

Comment: 3D frames should be 3D models. The business purpose is that I allow registered user upload different 3D model files. When other users review the file, he or she does not need to download the whole file (size about several Gbs), he or she could make preview the 3D model files with a couple of snapshots made by of camera with different angle. In this way, he or she could know about the 3D file roughtly, then decide to download or not.

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/34540/599